# Name of Legendre symbol?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

This may seem stupid question, but I'm curious about this.

Generally, $(a/p)$ is called "the Legendre symbol" where $p$ is an odd prime, but I don't like this naming since this naming is not formal. That is, this terminology is not designating a specific object.

Does it sound OK to call $(a/p)$ "the Legendre symbol of $a$ mod $p$" or "the Legendre symbol of $a$ over $p$"?

What about naming the function $(-/p):\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ "the Legendre symbol mod $p$?

What would be a good terminology to emphasize a subject $a$ or emphasize $(-/p)$ as a function?

Comment: When the function aspect is emphasized, usually called a character

Comment: @WillJagy Can you give me the full-name?

Comment: I do not believe I know a full name... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_character   and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_%28mathematics%29

Comment: This has been asked a few years ago at Mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15447/is-there-a-standard-way-to-read-the-legendre-symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the Legendre question it should be "a on p". But I could be wrong.

Comment: I agree with this! :)